# Is it possible to change the font size of the title of tool windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: problem example][image: example 2]

How do I change the font of these titles. they are larger than the global font and the editor font.

Comment: The font size is not separately configurable; it depends on the selected look & feel. Which look & feel are you using?

Comment: intellij default theme

Comment: Which OS is that? Did you change the system DPI settings?

Comment: Linux x64. i am using openjdk8 with font fix
http://urshulyak.com/?p=478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible via options within IntelliJ `Settings`.

The font styles of virtually everything within an editor are customizable, but not the tool window panes as per your question.

Having said that, you might want to experiment with the different Look&Feel settings, there may be some slight differences in size.